# Using multiple filtered 5V rails, derived from a common PSU, together?

Tags: power, circuit-design, voltage-regulator, noise, decoupling-capacitor

I'm trying to design a peripheral circuit which will attach to a BBC Master (1980s home computer) via one or more of its external ports (*specifically the RGB, Analogue, and User ports*). Each port carries a 5V supply I could use to power my peripheral. My dilemma is that a schematic of the Master's system board shows that it uses multiple 5V rails internally and not all the external ports are on the same rails (*specifically the User port is on a different rail to the RGB and Analogue ports*).

When I say multiple rails, the PSU produces a single 5V output from its smoothing capacitors, but several parallel inductor/capacitor filtering/decoupling circuits on the system board then produce separate filtered rails that power different subsets of the ICs and external ports (see diagram below).

Let's say that I would like my peripheral to power itself from the external ports it's connected to, and it may be connected to either I/Oa, I/Ob, or both I/Oa and I/Ob. My question is then, is it possible to use/tie 5Va and 5Vb together (and 0Va and 0Vb together) in some fashion and use that?

- The Master's system board schematic passes logic signals between ICs on different sets of rails without ceremony so I assume they're broadly electrically compatible (e.g. the filtering circuit doesn't produce a DC offset).
- The potential problem seems to me that electrical noise/load could pass between the previously isolated A and B rails via the peripheral. If I tied the supplies together in the peripheral circuit with another 47µF capacitor between the rails, would that be sufficient to maintain adequate isolation between the A and B rails on the system board? Or, do I need something more elaborate?

[image: Diagram of a system with two separately filtered 5V rails]

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Your question's technically but too abstract about the application. Which port on the BBC Master are you connecting to and on which ports are you considering paralleling the 5 V outputs? Please edit this info into your question, don't post it in comments. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly unusual circuit having inductors (value?) in both the OV and the 5V rails, but I suppose they knew what they were doing. As you note, signals pass between circuits powered from 5Va and 5Vb so your peripheral should be OK doing the same. However is there any specification for how much current you can draw from any one port to power your device? You may be able to power your peripheral from only one of the two supplies. There must have been a good reason why it was designed like that, so connecting them together externally would defeat that. I can't think of any additional filtering configuration that would allow you to join them together and still ensure adequate isolation. Could you device be self powered (battery or its own PSU) ?

Answer (score 3):

They've made an EMC nightmare, and I'm guessing it's also not a groundplane based design but just free-for-all wiring under a metal can, as was the style at the time?

Definitely avoid using fast logic with it; 74HC might even be a stretch?  Design your logic to tolerate poor signal quality, runt pulses; use filtering + schmitt triggers on all signals you can; etc.

I might suggest common mode filtering for signals bridging between buses, but I suspect it wouldn't make any difference anyway due to the care-free internal design.  On the upside, it probably makes no further difference if you just bridge the two ports together; a little extra grounding probably isn't going to worsen an already terrible EMC situation.

Comment: (`style at the time` can you remember modifying/thinking up designs *before* formal education, means for meaningful simulations at your disposal, WWW? Then again, *BBC*)

Comment: This answer reads more negatively than I intended, I think, but engineering has always been engineering, whatever the means for resources and experience (or lack thereof, as the case may be). They weren't without EMC standards at the time either. To be clear, 2-layer PCBs were affordable, and clock rates were low, so they did what they could.  But also to be clear, I'm guessing they passed EMC without additional active circuitry plugged into these ports, or bridging them. In modern context, the lack of ground plane is a "nightmare", i.e., you have no reference voltage to start from.

Comment: (*engineering* is exactly why I asked about memories about *before* [your personal] *formal education* in EE.)

Answer (score 3):

At least according to page 11 of [this version](https://github.com/simoninns/Acorn-Master-AIV/blob/master/Schematics/Acorn%20Master%20128/Acorn%20Master%20128/PDF/Acorn%20Master%20128.pdf) of the BBC Master 128 schematic the inductors in your diagram are marked as WL (Wire Link) and some of the capacitors as NF (Not Fitted). I suggest first confirm which of the two schematics matches the actual board.

Comment: You are correct that the "inductors" on the actual PCB appear to be just straight wires soldered between the terminals. That does make the circuit simpler (although a straight wire can have inductance, it's presumably very small).